# How to keep original index after training and splitting

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a df and I am doing a train/test split. My question is how do I keep the original index after splitting?

[Before splitting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PFvGw.png)

[After splitting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/al2Wq.png)

This is my code :

X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(X_train_res,y_train_res,test_size=0.25,random_state=42)

Comment: What do you mean by index, do you mean the order in which the rows are? In that case try `train_test_split(X_train_res,y_train_res,test_size=0.25,random_state=42, shuffle=False)`.

Comment: Yes basically the customer info (the index) gets changed to a number and its not in order

Comment: I would also like to shuffle the data if possible

Comment: Move the index to a new column in the dataframe(s) you are splitting, e.g., `X_train_res = X_train_res.reset_index()`. You can remove it from the split data before training.

Comment: @Alexk thank you for your response, but I am not following.

Comment: @Ramish, I can't reproduce your problem without a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), not knowing exactly what the `X_train_res` and `y_train_res` objects are and how they relate to the images you posted, but my point was that if your index changes when you run `train_test_split`, you can just convert that index into another column in your dataframe prior to splitting, giving you access to those values after the split.